# Gradle: Execution failed for task ':test'. > No tests found for given includes:

Tags: java, gradle, junit

I try to run this single unit test of [this open-source project on GitHub](https://github.com/Verisimilitude11/DNAnalyzer) with IntelliJ.

```
Execution failed for task ':test'.
No tests found for given includes: [DNAnalyzer.MainTest.mainClassshouldExist](--tests filter)
```

### The test class

```
package DNAnalyzer;


import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class MainTest {
  @Test
  public void mainClassshouldExist() throws ClassNotFoundException {
     Class.forName("DNAnalyzer.Main");
  }
}
```

### The build.gradle

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java application project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the 'Building Java & JVM projects' chapter in the Gradle
 * User Manual available at https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/building_java_projects.html
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in Java.
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Use JUnit test framework.
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.9.1'


    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation "com.google.guava:guava:31.0.1-jre"

    // Picocli
    implementation "info.picocli:picocli:4.6.3"
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = "DNAnalyzer.Main"
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'DNAnalyzer.Main'
    }

    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

### What I have tried

- Updating to the newest JUnit

  testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.9.1'
- Adding this to my build.gradle file:

  test {
  useJUnitPlatform()
  }

### The only workaround yet:

When I go to Settings -> Build-Tool -> Gradle and set the Test execution to "Run tests wit: IntelliJ IDEA" the tests are executed correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the latest Intellij IDEA? It looks like a bug which must be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is coming from the naming of the package which contains your test classes, `DNAnalyzer`, which does not really follow java naming conventions as it's starts with/contains capital letters.

When executing single test case or test class, IntelliJ will delegate to Gradle  by invoking `test` task with a specific filter, as follows
`./gradlew :test --tests "DNAnalyzer.MainTest.mainClassshouldExist"`

And in Gradle there is this issue : https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/20350 : "test --tests does not work with packages which contain capital letters".

Try to move your test classes in another well-named package and you won't have this issue.